# Java Bytecode decompilation -- Unused Methods Present?

Tags: java, methods, bytecode, decompiler

Say I have

```
private void ThisIsMySecurityMethodPleaseLookHERE() {
//security stuff
}
```

In my program, but that method is called nowhere in any of the actually executed code.  Does it get compiled to bytecode?  Or does the Java compiler recognize that fact and filter it out?  I know it would never make it PAST bytecode, since it is not truly called.

I ask because I know Java is notoriously easy to decompile.  would all of my unused methods also be present when they decompile one of my .class files?

I assume that this is not the case, since, were it the case, every java file would have bloat code to hide the real code, and be passed through an obfuscator.

I'm just trying to think of methods other than obfuscation to resist the casual hacker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why assume anything? Use `javap -c` to see what's in the byte code.

Given that the compiler can't know whether the private method might be called by reflection, I'd expect it to still be present, personally.

I'm not sure what you mean by this:

> I assume that this is not the case, since, were it the case, every java file would have bloat code to hide the real code, and be passed through an obfuscator.

I would hope that most developers would realise that security through obscurity is little protection at all - but also that the true value of the code itself is usually in the design etc, rather than just the implementation. So no, don't include sensitive information in your classes - but equally don't get too paranoid. You need to weigh up the costs of trying to defeat attackers with the cost of them "winning". That balance will depend on the code involved - and also the kind of attack you're trying to guard against.

Comment: +1 for teaching how to determine what's in the final byte code.

Comment: I work in the oil field, where the price of an individual software license (around $10,000 per copy, to $140,000 per copy) is great incentive to disable licensing tests.  I meant that I can see a situation where everyone programming in Java would add a bunch of bloat code, then run it through an obfuscator to deter that kind of thing.  Not ideal, but definitely possible.  ALSO: Thank you for the `javap` command reminder.

Comment: @Sheriff: Not everyone works in a similar environment, and indeed a *lot* of Java code is deployed on servers, where the end user or customer may never have access to the bytecode anyway. Do many oil companies engage in software piracy? I'd be surprised if they'd risk it, but who knows...

Comment: @Jon Skeet If you can get away with it, yes they do.  In many instances it's not even about getting the software for free, simply getting it to work.  I can only speak about Directional Drilling, but there is a VERY strong software piracy market in it.  It is a nasty cut throat industry.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  As an additional example, much of the hardware in use by the major companies is still equipped 486 or 586 processors.  Sometimes the architects of that software have since moved on, and hacking is the only way to port the software to new hardware.  It's a very different world from what most Stackers are used to.

Answer (score 1):

The private method will actually make it to byte code. Maybe even assembly code. You have to think of all these methods get translated to routines. So for any private method that is not being used there will still be a routine in byte code block.

On a different note, there are tools out there that clean this stuff up and remove excessive code/classes that are not being used. If that is the case then, yes you don't have them in the decompiled code.

Comment: Thank you Amir.  I will start scoping through all of this with the byte code perusal Jon Skeet mentioned.  Y'all have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Test and see that you need to add option `-p` (aka `-private`) to get private methods content.